# How to Create the parsing of these response in Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Hey there i am totaly beginner in retrofit.
Please ,anyone can tell me how to store this details in object using **retrofit**,like we create in asyctask using jsonObject and jsonArray?.

```
 {"status":"1","error_msg":"","data":[{"id":"22","title":"xxx","type":"xxx","rate":"xxx","order_by":"xxx","pic":[{"file_name":"xxx"},{"file_name":"xxx"},{"file_name":"xxx"}],"description":" xxx","status":"1"}]}
```

Comment: You can also parse this data using JSONObject and JSONArray

Comment: You can use online converters like http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: this is a good tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

Answer (score 0):

First visit this site: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
this will generate your response holder classes, where you can store the responses.

Thank you have to create the following:

```
ServerResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ServerResponse.class);
```

you can access your data by response.getStatus() etc....